# Recommended method/place for registering RxJava plugins

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am looking to address a similar problem described [here](http://blog.mabn.pl/2014/11/rxjava-logback-and-mdc-threadlocal.html).  The solution is simple, but requires registering custom RxJava plugins.  From a Spring Boot/Cloud perspective, is there a recommended method/place/way for doing this?

For the win...  this is a mechanism for copying thread local variables.  Has there been any thought on the best way to propagate the spring security context (default is a threadlocal) when using Observables?

-Joshua

Comment: Hello !
Did you find a solution to your problem ?